# Detecting hardware keyboard key press under iPadOS 14.x with SwiftUI 2.0

Tags: swiftui, ios14, swiftui-windowgroup, windowgroup

i'm trying to add hardware keyboard support for an iOS 14.0 app written in SwiftUI 2.0.
I saw some examples working with UIHostingController, so i'd like to try this way on iOS14/SWiftui 2.0 using WindowGroup.

I'm gettin gerror when compiling in XCODe 12.3
"*Generic struct 'WindowGroup' requires that 'KeyTestController' conform to 'View'*"

ContentView() conforms to View and everything is working fine when not using the "KeyTestController" class.

Any way to solve this ?

Thank you very much.

```
import SwiftUI
import StoreKit
import UIKit

@main
struct myApp: App
{
    var body: some Scene
    {
        WindowGroup
        {
            KeyTestController(rootView:ContentView())
        }
    }
}

class KeyTestController<Content>: UIHostingController<Content> where Content: View
{
 /* CODE …… */
}
```

Comment: KeyTestController has to be View or UIViewControllerRepresentable or UIViewRepresentable. Not a UIHostingController

Comment: UIHostingController is needed to override keyCommands and detect the hardware key press and handle it

Comment: Maybe put that in a UIViewController and then a UIViewControllerRepresentable